# Примет ли AppStore такое приложение?

Tags: appstore

Решили создать приложение для клиентов, они пользуются iphone. Задались вопросом, **а примут ли?** Кто в теме, подскажите.

Приложение дает возможность отправить заявку на обмен валюты (сумма, валюты, курс). После чего с клиентом связываются по телефону. **Электронных обменов через приложение - нет.**

Предварительно клиент должен зарегистрироваться, указав свой телефон (пройти SMS проверку), имя и город.

Прототип главного меню и заявки:

[image]

Остальные страницы:
 - О нас: краткое описание про
   программу, версия и пр. инфо данные.
   Архив: история подачи заявок на
   обмен. Новости: текстовые новости
   компании.

**Все. Примет ли AppStore? Никто из знакомых точно не говорит. Помогите узнать.**

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он не имеет отношения ни к программированию, ни к администрированию.

Answer (score 0):

Нормальное приложение, публикуйте. Вот правила (на англ в эппле можете найти):
http://touchin.ru/letters/pravila-priema-prilozhenii-v-app-store/